# Hide all table rows except items with IDs defined in filtering object

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am working on a Table Row filtering script.

Initially, the all table rows are visible, but after manipulating some dropdowns / forms the filter criteria dictate which rows are going to be visible and which not. Example:

```js
var jobs = [{
  id: 0,
  company: "Google",
  location: "Zurich"
}, {
  id: 1,
  company: "Facebook",
  location: "Ireland"
}];

// this function isn't run in this example for reasons of brevity. it's to show how the jobs array is generated
const filterRow = function (data, filters) {
  let filtersEnabled = Object.keys(filters).filter(element => filters[element].length !== 0);
  return data.filter(row => {
    return filtersEnabled.every(k => {
      return filters[k].indexOf(row[k]) !== -1
    })
  })
}

let $tableRows = $('table tbody tr');

const updateDisplay = function() {
  // that's not ideal
  $tableRows.addClass('hidden')
  jobs.forEach((row) => {
    $(`[data-id="${row.id}"]`).removeClass('hidden')
  })
}

$('.js-filter').on('click', () => updateDisplay())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<button class="js-filter">filter table now</button>
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tbody>
    <tr data-company="google" data-id="0" data-loation="zurich">
      <td>Google</td>
      <td>Zurich</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-company="facebook" data-id="1" data-loation="ireland">
      <td>Facebook</td>
      <td>Ireland</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-company="microsoft" data-id="2" data-loation="california">
      <td>microsoft</td>
      <td>California</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The jobs array determines which rows are going to be visible. (so in this particular case, only rows with id 0 and 1 are going to be visible.

Given that the jobs array is changing programmatically, I would like a jQuery (or other) way to directly hide the rows with ID not present in the array (thus being able to use [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) to fade rows out etc.

What I currently do is

1. hiding all rows,
2. then showing the ones in the array. That's rather a workaround and it complicates my transitions/animations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the jQuery [`.filter()` method](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to iterate over the rows and filter them.

On each iteration you can check to see if the row's `data-id` attribute is found in the `jobs` array by using the [`.some()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some). From there, you can return the boolean and filter out rows that have an `id` that matches an object in the `jobs` array.

```
$rows.filter((index, row) => {
  return !jobs.some(job => job.id === +row.dataset.id);
}).addClass('hidden');
```

Alternatively, you could also use the jQuery [`.not()` method](http://api.jquery.com/not/) in place of `.filter()`:

```
$rows.not((index, row) => {
  return jobs.some(job => job.id === +row.dataset.id);
}).addClass('hidden');
```

Or if you want to break `isJobById` into another function:

```
const isJobById = id => jobs.some(job => job.id === +id);
const updateDisplay = () => {
  $rows.not((i, row) => isJobById(row.dataset.id)).addClass('hidden');
}
```

You can also change the following line:

```
$('.js-filter').on('click', () => updateDisplay());
```

.. and pass the `updateDisplay` function directly:

```
$('.js-filter').on('click', updateDisplay);
```

Full snippet:

```js
var jobs = [{
  id: 0,
  company: "Google",
  location: "Zurich"
}, {
  id: 1,
  company: "Facebook",
  location: "Ireland"
}];

let $rows = $('table tbody tr');
const isJobById = id => jobs.some(job => job.id === +id);
const updateDisplay = () => {
  $rows.not((i, row) => isJobById(row.dataset.id)).addClass('hidden');
}

$('.js-filter').on('click', updateDisplay);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<button class="js-filter">filter table now</button>
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tbody>
    <tr data-company="google" data-id="0" data-loation="zurich">
      <td>Google</td>
      <td>Zurich</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-company="facebook" data-id="1" data-loation="ireland">
      <td>Facebook</td>
      <td>Ireland</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-company="microsoft" data-id="2" data-loation="california">
      <td>microsoft</td>
      <td>California</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks, works, accepted, but two questions: 1/ could we use .not() for this and simplify it? I'm actually running another loop which generates the `jobs` array so wondering if I could do it directly there?.. (check updated question) 2/ is there any way we can use "===" instead of "==" ? I know the id is a number and not a string..

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos - Okay, I added an example using the `.not()` method. I'm not sure what data you're passing to the `filterRow` function, so I am not sure about that... For 2), I updated it to use `===`. The reason I was initially using `==` is because the data attributes were returning a string, (i.e., `typeof row.dataset.id` was `string`). I just added a `+` before the attribute value to coerce it into a number.